# SAS Regression by class variable

Tags: macros, sas

I wish to perform multiple regressions conditionally based on the value of a categorical variable.  So, for a simple example, consider the sashelp.class data.  I need to perform a regression for males and another for females.  Since my dataset has many more divisions and is much larger, I start by feeding the different types into macro variables:

```
proc sql;
    select count(distinct Sex) into :numsex
    from sashelp.class;
    %let numsex=&numsex;
    select distinct Sex into :sex1 - :sex&numsex
    from sashelp.class;
quit;
```

Then I am trying to perform a regression on each one by looping them through.  I know the commented out code works, but am unsure why my macro function is not working.

```
/**/
/*data dataF;*/
/*  set sashelp.class;*/
/*  where Sex='F';*/
/*run;*/
/**/
/*proc reg data=dataF outest=out1;*/
/*  model Height=Weight;*/
/*run;*/

%macro regress;
%do i = 1 %to &numsex;

data data&&sex&i;
    set sashelp.class;
    where Sex='&&sex&i';
run;

proc reg data=data&&sex&i outest=out&i;
    model Height=Weight;
run;
%end;
%mend;
%regress;
```

Also, if there is a better way to do this, then I'm all ears.  The current way is a pain since I will have to combine all of my output sets of the estimates to get one dataset.  Also, I get a bunch of intermediate datasets that I don't want or need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the BY group is the best way to do this, not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for:

```
proc sort data=sashelp.class out=class;
by sex;
run;

proc reg data=class outest=out1;
  by sex;
  model Height=Weight;
run;
```

Your macro failed because single quotes stop macro variable resolution (ie, '&sex' does not work to get 'F'; you have to use "&sex" to get "F".)

Comment: Thanks, Joe.  I don't know why I was trying to make this so difficult.